# remove noise while preserving peak

Tags: list-manipulation, signal-processing

I have a data (see [this link](https://pastebin.com/raw/U0rDQLpK)) which has some wiggles at both end.

I tried to apply different filters to smooth the data, like this

```
ListLinePlot[{data, MeanFilter[data, 2]}]
```

[image]

The wiggles are perfectly smooth. However, the problem is that the main peak is also severely drop down(show in green circle) which is not what I want. I also tried other filter like `LowpassFilter`, `GaussianFilter`, all suffers this problem.

So how to **remove small wiggles and preserve main peak of a data**? Splitting data to piecewise may not be a good idea, because I have dozens of data to smooth, their main peaks are not at the same locations.

Comment: It is clear, that you will have certain decrease of your function values when some high-freq Fourier components removed. I guess you can re-normalize you function using the ratio of areas under the curve before and after filtering. It can be like this: `newF[x]=(Integrate[F[x],{x,a,b}]/Integrate[filteredF[x],{x,a,b}])*filteredF[x]`

Answer (score 2):

You need a **nonlinear filter** like `MeanShiftFilter` to do that. `MeanShiftFilter` asks for a radius and a threshold, which have to be set according to the noise in your data. `MeanShiftFilter[data, 10, 50]` gives this result:

[image: MeanShiftFilter]

The peak value is preserved:

```
Max /@ {MeanShiftFilter[data, 10, 50], data}
{802.993, 802.993}
```